# playwright conditional page.waitForNavigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, playwright

When automating a login for, I perform click on an element that it could lead to navigation to another page but in case of invalid password it will just display error message on the same page without actually causing a navigation.

I have tried:

```
await Promise.all([
      this.page.submitButton.click(),
      this.page.waitForNavigation()
    ]);
```

But it will fail for the case when no navigation happens.
I was thinking about interception the response, to check if the login succeed/failed, but may be there is a more clear way to do so ?

Answer (score 4):

This code should give you an example of how to understand if you stay on the same page or navigate:

```js
await this.page.submitButton.click();

try {
    await this.page.waitForNavigation();
    // if we are here it means login was successful
} catch(e) {
    // if we are here it means login failed
}
```

Comment: thank you, in such case the waitForNavigation() will exit only on time-out, right ?

Comment: @Zaky exactly. But you can check some exact thing instead of waitForNavigation. For example, you might check an error message in case of the wrong password. But it also implies waiting I guess.

Comment: i wanted to avoid waiting for the waitForNavigation, but what is worked for me was the opposite approach. I just waited for the selector with short time-out and if it failed (meaning the page started navigation, i called to await page.waitForNavigation().

Comment: @Zaky maybe you also might waitForNavigation() with a short timeout

Comment: i afraid that it can introduce an race condition, since in case the navigation actually should take place i will need to call again for the waitForNavigation on some hardcoded timeout

Comment: @Zaky, do you mind posting the final solution that you chose?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need some extra code besides `this.page.submitButton.click()`.
The [click](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-click) function will wait for the navigation for you. So you could check after the click if your are in the same URL or not.

```
await this.page.submitButton.click(); // This will wait for a possible navigation

if(this.page.url() == destinationOnValidLogin) {
 // Good login stuff
} else {
 // Login failed
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the click() will return as soon as navigation started, before the page is completely loaded. On the other hand, in my scenario click() could lead only to new request to update the page without actually causing the navigation.
Ideally, I want to distinguish these flows: if click() caused only update or actual navigation.

Comment: According to the doc click will `Wait for initiated navigations to either succeed or fail, unless noWaitAfter option is set.`

Comment: Do you mean that i can click with option noWaitAfter set, (assuming the click with return when page is updated or started navigation) and then to check for page.$('some-marker) - exists otherwise call to page.waitForNavigation() ?

Comment: You don't need to set `noWaitAfter`, that's the default behavior. I added a code a example. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: well, it doesn't. If I check the page url just after calling await this.page.click(), I'm getting the same url (in both cases).
moreover, i tried to intercept responses from the back-end to check the login success / failed - i couldn't get it since the request was originated form the service worker, and surprisingly playwright doesn't intercept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two competing promises to `await` for here - one for the error message to appear, and another one for navigation to happen.
Only one will initially resolve, hence we can use [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) to avoid excessive waiting or code branching.

```
await submitButton.click({
  noWaitAfter: true, // since we are handling potential navigation ourselves
});

// adding custom then callbacks to distinguish between the two
const navigationPromise = page.waitForURL('**').then(() => true);
const errorMessagePromise = messageLocator.isVisible().then(() => false);

const isLoggedIn = await Promise.any([
  navigationPromise,
  errorMessagePromise,
]);

// at this stage we have either new page loaded OR login form with error message displayed
```

See [`waitUntil`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame#frame-wait-for-url-option-wait-until) option of `waitForURL` method for more precise control of page navigation event you are interested in.